# Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() to set the property (of [object Object]) to `[object Object]`

Tags: javascript, networking, ember.js, websocket

I am trying to integrate a Javascript library I'm building with EmberJS.

Example almost working integration:
https://github.com/pubnub/open-chat-framework/blob/ember/examples/ember

The library returns a single object with many nested objects. The library is based on network events, so the child objects are updated periodically without user input. The updated fire events that can be listened to.

This causes problems for EmberJS, because Ember requires every property update to be done via `Ember.set()` which my library does not use.

The library is a general purpose JS library so I am refusing to add Ember specific code to it. I am wondering how to solve the above error without rewriting my library.

How can I wrap an event based library in a way Ember would like? I have previously tried globals and an Ember service.

In other examples I have seen people wrap every method of the library in Ember specific code. This seems repetitive.

Is it possible to manually tell Ember of changes to the root object and have Ember ignore all other changes? Meaning, can I have ember NOT observe changes and manually tell ember when things change?

The library includes a root event emitter that is notified of all changes to any object within the tree.

```
ember-cli: 2.11.1
node: 6.7.0
os: darwin x64
```

Comment: This sounds like a tough problem yo

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the awesome lib you created.

Everybody wants to use it, should use it in the way of ember.

Just need to change controller of example like this :

````
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    OCF: null,
    me: null,
    messages: [],
    messageInput: '',
    init: function() {

        this._super(...arguments);

        // test
        let OCF = window.OpenChatFramework.create({
          rltm: {
              service: 'pubnub', 
              config: {
                  publishKey: 'pub-c-07824b7a-6637-4e6d-91b4-7f0505d3de3f',
                  subscribeKey: 'sub-c-43b48ad6-d453-11e6-bd29-0619f8945a4f',
                  restore: false
              }
          },
          globalChannel: 'ocf-demo-ember-2'
        });
    this.set('OCF', OCF);

        // create a user for myself and store as ```me```
        let me = this.get('OCF').connect(new Date().getTime());
    this.set('me', me);

        this.get('me').plugin(window.OpenChatFramework.plugin.randomUsername(this.get('OCF').globalChat));

        this.get('OCF').globalChat.on('message', (payload) => {
          console.log(payload)
          this.get('messages').pushObject(payload);
        });

    },
    actions: {
        sendChat: function() {
            let messageInput = this.get('messageInput');
            if(messageInput) {

                this.get('OCF').globalChat.send('message', {
                    text: messageInput
                });

                Ember.set(this, 'messageInput', '');

            }

            return false;

        }
    }
});
````

Comment: I tried copy and pasting your code but I get the same error. Some sub value of OCF gets updated asynchronously and does not use ```.set()```. I can't update that code directly. Is there a way to deep watch objects for changes and disable ember's automatic sync?

Comment: @IanJennings I could get the example in the github work by this